# Calling My REST API Using C#

Tags: c#, json, api, rest, client

I'm trying to call my own REST API that returns JSON using a simple C# GUI application, and am looking for the simplest way to do so:

```
http://danielmiessler.com:44821/token/dGVxdWllcm8=
```

I am opening a file containing tokens and reading the contents line by line to get the final part of the URL:

```
StreamReader input = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.OpenFile());

while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null) {
```

This is going back into a textbox:

```
textBox2.Text += ("\t" + result + "\r\n");
```

Here is the Ruby code I'm trying to reproduce:

```
# Get our libraries 
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

# Get our input from the command line
input = ARGV[0]

# Loop through the file
File.open("#{input}", "r").each_line do |line|
    # Request the URL
    response = HTTParty.get("http://danielmiessler.com:44821/token/#{line.chomp}")
    # Go through the responses
    case response.code
    when 400
        print "Improper input…\n"
        # Feel free to remove this line if you want to reduce output.
    when 200
        json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        print "Your input is #{json['type']} of the word: #{json['value']}\n"
    when 404
        print "There is no meaning in your token…\n"
        # Feel free to remove this line if you want to reduce output.
    end
end
```

Any ideas how to make the calls based on the tokens in the file and output to the text box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

This is a [minimal example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee) to get you started:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

    client.GetAsync(_address).ContinueWith( 
        (requestTask) => 
        { 
            HttpResponseMessage response = requestTask.Result; 
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
            response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonArray>().ContinueWith( 
                (readTask) => 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine(
                     "First 50 countries listed by The World Bank..."); 
                    foreach (var country in readTask.Result[1]) 
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine("   {0}, Country Code: {1}, " +
                            "Capital: {2}, Latitude: {3}, Longitude: {4}", 
                            country.Value["name"], 
                            country.Value["iso2Code"], 
                            country.Value["capitalCity"], 
                            country.Value["latitude"], 
                            country.Value["longitude"]); 
                    } 
                }); 
        }); 
    Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit..."); 
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a GUI app, not console. I'm trying to return the results to the textbox2 I mentioned.